# Typed Generic Key Value Interface in Typescript

Tags: typescript, generics, type-inference, typescript2.0, typescript-generics

I have the following example Object:

```
let foo: Foo = {
  'key1': { default: 'foo', fn: (val:string) => val },
  'key2': { default: 42, fn: (val:number) => val },

  // this should throw an error, because type of default and fn don't match
  'key3': { default: true, fn: (val:string) => val }
}
```

The Interface should look something like this:

```
interface Foo {
  [key: string]: { default: T, fn: (val:T) => any }
}
```

This of course doesn't work, because there's no `T` defined.

So I thought about doing this:

```
interface FooValue<T> {
  default: T;
  fn: (val:T) => any;
}

interface Foo {
  [key: string]: FooValue<?>
}
```

But there I got stuck, too. Because I can't define the generic type of `FooValue`.

If I use `FooValue<any>` then of course everything is typed as `any`. Though that doesn't work.

I want to ensure that the type of `default` and the parameter type of `fn` are always the same.

Is there any solution? Or can't this be done?

Comment: what about `interface Foo<T>`?

Comment: Then I have to define `T` when doing `let foo: Foo<???> = {...}`. Then I would set the generic type for every key. This way all the `FooValue` objects must be the same type. But as you can see in the example object: I want a different generic type for every key-value.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

How about defining `Foo<T>` to be a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types), like this:

```
interface FooValue<T> {
  default: T;
  fn: (val: T) => any;
}

type Foo<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: FooValue<T[K]>
}
```

In this case, if `T` is some normal object type like `{a: string, b: number, c: boolean}`, then `Foo<T>` is the `Foo`-ized version of it: `{a: FooValue<string>, b: FooValue<number>, c: FooValue<boolean>`}.  Now you can make a helper function which accepts an object literal only if it can be inferred as a `Foo<T>` for some type `T`:

```
function asFoo<T>(foo: Foo<T>): Foo<T> {
  return foo;
}
```

This function works because the TypeScript compiler can do [inference from mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#inference-from-mapped-types), allowing it to infer `T` from `Foo<T>`.  Here is it working:

```
let foo = asFoo({
  key1: { default: 'foo', fn: (val: string) => val },
  key2: { default: 42, fn: (val: number) => val }
});
// inferred as { key1: FooValue<string>; key2: FooValue<number>;}
```

And here is it failing:

```
let badFoo = asFoo(
  key1: { default: 'foo', fn: (val: string) => val },
  key2: { default: 42, fn: (val: number) => val },
  key3: { default: true, fn: (val: string) => val }
}); 
// error! Types of property 'key3' are incompatible. 
// Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

---

Update: The above code assumes you're okay with `foo.key1.fn('abc')` being inferred as type `any`, since `FooValue<string>['fn']` is defined as a function that returns `any`.  It kind of forgets the output type from the original object literal.  If you want `foo` to *remember* the return type of its properties' `fn` methods, you can do this slightly different helper function:

```
function asFoo<T, F>(foo: F & Foo<T>): F {
  return foo;
}

let foo = asFoo({
  key1: { default: 'foo', fn: (val: string) => val },
  key2: { default: 42, fn: (val: number) => val },
  // next line would cause error
  // key3: { default: true, fn: (val: string)=>val} 
})

const key1fnOut = foo.key1.fn('s') // known to be string
const key2fnOut = foo.key2.fn(123) // known to be number
```

And that works.  In this case, `asFoo()` just verifies that the input is a `Foo<T>` for some `T`, but it doesn't coerce the output type to a `Foo<T>`.  Depending on your use cases, you may prefer this solution to the other one.  Good luck again.

Comment: Thank you! Awesome help! The helper function was all I needed, I guess.

Comment: @jcalz considering this is an old answer and TS has also upgraded, is there a better way to do it now, especially the `F&Foo<T>` part ?