# Enforce object to contain all keys of an enum and still have type inference for it's values

Tags: typescript, enums

I have an object and I want to enforce it to contain all keys of an Enum, and I also want the type of it’s values to be inferred.
So if I do this:

```
enum RequiredKeys {
    A = 'a',
    B = 'b'
}
const objectThatShouldContainAllRequiredKeys = {
    [RequiredKeys.A]: (id: string) => {}
};
// Argument of type '123' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'
// Which is great, that's exactly what I want. 
objectThatShouldContainAllRequiredKeys[RequiredKeys.A](123);
```

But now, I tried enforcing the object keys and every solution I try breaks the type inference. For example:

```
enum RequiredKeys {
    A = 'a',
    B = 'b'
}
// Property 'b' is missing in type '{ a: (id: string) => void; }' but required in type 'Record<RequiredKeys, Function>'.
// Which is great, that's exactly what I want
const objectThatShouldContainAllRequiredKeys: Record<RequiredKeys, Function> = {
    [RequiredKeys.A]: (id: string) => {}
};
// No error here, which is less great...
objectThatShouldContainAllRequiredKeys[RequiredKeys.A](123);
```

Any idea how I can enjoy both worlds? Have the object enforce all keys from the enum and infer the object values?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create identity function with type parameter constrained to have required keys, so typescript will validate the passed object keys and will infer its values' types:

```
const createWithRequiredKeys = <T extends Record<RequiredKeys, unknown>>(obj: T) => obj;

const withRequiredKeys = createWithRequiredKeys({
    [RequiredKeys.A]: (id: string) => {},
    [RequiredKeys.B]: 'foo',
}); 

// withRequiredKeys is { a: (id: string) => void; b: string; }

withRequiredKeys[RequiredKeys.A](123); // 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBASsCOYCWAnYATA0sAngZygG8BYAKCigEEoBeKAcgEN6AaMigIVoYCN6yAvmTIBjAPYg8AFygi0jKcADqSKQAs4iVBmz5uAHgAqUYAA9FIdATjiU6fZuRosuPCyhgQAaxBiA7iAAfIEAFGI8AFYAXFCGAJS0gVDhEQDcwqTikjJ+qhoITjqu3HLACsp5jtou+CEk5FAA2lXOungAdJQAujEhSOgx0ihIIADmCTRJhFACbA3NBdVt7Rw9DABmYmKsgnHppGQA9IdQueotRXpIBNOMvf2DUsNjE0kAbmL9qVA8j8+j3yEB1IZ3yWlargW4MuHW6IQAjAAmADMeygxwY4AgPGAKHoUGuUF8MkYeDwSFGIEYPAANsAoFIxFAAA6MFCMCDARQoZLrBk4Zn0+hDEajehAA)

Answer (score 0):

Fast solution: (**SECOND UPDATE**)

```js
enum RequiredKeys {
  A = 'a',
  B = 'b'
}

type Mapped = {
  [RequiredKeys.A]: (id: string) => any,
  [RequiredKeys.B]: (id: number) => any
}

// Property 'b' is missing in type '{ a: (id: string) => void; }' but required in type 'Record<RequiredKeys, Function>'.
// Which is great, that's exactly what I want
const objectThatShouldContainAllRequiredKeys: Mapped = {
  [RequiredKeys.A]: (id: string) => { },
  [RequiredKeys.B]: (id: number) => { }
}
// No error here, which is less great...
const result = objectThatShouldContainAllRequiredKeys[RequiredKeys.A]('ok'); // ok
const result2 = objectThatShouldContainAllRequiredKeys[RequiredKeys.B](1); // ok

const result3 = objectThatShouldContainAllRequiredKeys[RequiredKeys.B]('1'); // error
const result4 = objectThatShouldContainAllRequiredKeys[RequiredKeys.A](2); // error
```

If you want more generic solution, you can take a look on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65167619/create-a-generic-type-from-enum/65168065#65168065)

Please keep in mind, that in case of more generic solution, you should create a type map for enum and function types

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't enforce that all keys must exist in the object. I mean, if I remove the [RequiredKeys.B] record I won't get any error saying I must add it.

Comment: With your update the last two lines don't produce an error anymore :-/
And thanks again for your help!